# How do you style the scrolling part in jScrollPane?

Tags: scrollbar, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I have no idea how to style the box that you drag to scroll on jScrollPane. I have tried `.jspScrollBar`; no luck.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/n8Xgz/10/)

Comment: Looks like it works for me.  What browser?

Comment: Chrome version 27.  I see a green scroll bar. Is that what you were trying to do?

Comment: You know the part where you drag the box up and down to scroll? I'm trying to make that `#009900`

Comment: Right, the scrollbar? Right now it looks green to me (`lightgreen` as you put in the `.jspVerticalBar` and `.jspHorizontalBar` parts).  Try `#009900` instead of `lightgreen`.

Comment: That makes the _track_ `#009900`, instead of the little box

Comment: Updated your fiddle with what I believe you want.  If it works, please consider selecting my response as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for Imagine Dragons lyrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle with the solution I think you are looking for.

Specifically, you change the color of the "drag" portion of the scrollbar using the `jspDrag` class like so:

```
.jspDrag {
  background-color: #000; /*Changes drag box to black */
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n8Xgz/16/